# config.consider_all_requests_local = false not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm editing the default 404.html in the /public folder, and want to check the styling and to also be sure that it is rendering on all non-listed URLs (e.g. localhost:3000/foo, or localhost:3000/sjkbgksjbnjkadnjkn, or whatever), but setting `config.consider_all_requests_local = false` is not having the intended effect of being able to see the 404 page, I still get the developer error page on any random, unlisted route. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: @sam yep, still shows the red rails error page - "No route matches [GET] "/foo"

Comment: And just to make sure, you are getting the development error page when working on your development environment and you're setting the requests_local to false in `config/environments/development.rb`?

Comment: @sam yep that's correct